# Having this issue in selenium Web driver.How to write xpath to identify the Web Element?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 2 buttons, *Cancel* and *Next* button, on the same page but it has only one id (see the below code). I wanted to press *Next*, but every time it is identifying the *Cancel* button only not and not the *Next* button. How can I resolve this issue?

```
<input class="button" type="button" onclick="closePage()" value="Close" name="newButton"/>
<input class="button" type="button" onclick="closePage()" value="Close" name="newButton"/>
```

Comment: check it may probably returning 2 buttons first for cancel and other for Next, so click next button.

Comment: Err, the below code doesn't show any Cancel button, nor any Next button. It also doesn't have the Selenium code.

Answer (score 0):

If it has only one id,you kan get it with name:

```
<input class="button" type="button" onclick="closePage()" value="Close" name="newButton"/>
<input class="button" type="button" onclick="cancelPage()" value="Cancel" name="newButton"/

document.getElementsByName("newButton")[0].value; 
document.getElementsByName("newButton")[1].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

IWebElement sublogin = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@text='Next']"));
sublogin.Click();

Try this